Identification of 32-pin circular connector
I would like to inquire information about the type of female 32-pin connector used in the I/O port shown in the picture. I have been looking for this connector for a couple of weeks now without any luck. Could you  help me in finding the model number of this connector or direct me where to look.
The connector is mounted on ISA DRTS64, which is an automatic relay test set (link to the product: https://www.doble.com/product/drts-64/). I'm looking for the same type of connector that will be used to connect the ISA DRTS64 (current connector) test set to a type of box (where the connector I'm looking for should go) that will break out the pins of the cable (picture of the cable is shown below).
The dimensions of the connector are 35 mm outer rim and 22 mm inner rim. The pin pitch is 3 mm.



There's literally countless of these, sorting under the super broad term "circular power connectors". To the point where the manufacturers themselves don't even know what part it might be if you ask them :) The most prominent manufacturers are Amphenol, Eaton/Souriau, ITT Cannon, TE Connectivity.

Have you tried asking the manufacturer? I would hope they know. Any luck with the manual?

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica When I tried to get in touch with the product's manufacturer, all I got back was, "This is an old female connector for I/O output." Additionally, the manual only describes how to use the connector; it says nothing about its type.

Oh, there's a cable too -- any name or mark on it?

@TimWilliams The cable appears to be samtec it has their logo, but I couldn't find it on the web.

That looks similar to a Bulgin connector I've used.

(Image from: https://www.bulgin.com/us/products/flex-cable-connector-pxp7010-pxm7010-series.html)
Perhaps if you'll find a compatible solution here:
https://www.bulgin.com/us/products/flex-cable-connector-pxp7010-pxm7010-series.html

Looking at the first 32-pin item in the list, I don't see anywhere that the keying is described. The picture certainly shows incompatible keying. Are you sure that the pictured unit is even 42mm?

Yes, it is a Bulgin, but not a 7000 series. It's a "Standard Buccaneer" series. However, Bulgin lists up to 25 contacts, not 32 contacts. Either it's a special that Bulgin made, or it's a knock off by a company that extended the range.

One way to approach it is a google image search :
Image search on connector 20pins
I found this : MS3112E14-19P

Google searches are personalized so your generic search link might not yield the same results for someone else. And the link will be dead soon.

I know, I was just trying to give a technics that hopefully could helps... Apparently not. seeing your down voting.
